# CakePHP error.log don't log specific request urls

Tags: cakephp, error-log, cakephp-2.x

In my Cakephp error.log I have a lot of request urls like this:

- Request URL: /blog/blogs/wp-login.php
- Request URL: /wp-login.php

I know that these are from bots to find exploits, though it bothers me having them inside my error.log as it clutters the important error messages.

Is there a way to filter out specific urls? I only found a way to filter specific error types.

Comment: Just deny access to these URLs via your webservers config? Most cheap solution that won't even hit php at all.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @burzum to getting me on the right track!

```
RewriteRule ^wp-login.php - [NC,L,R=404]              #bot
RewriteRule ^blog/blogs/wp-login.php - [NC,L,R=404]   #bot
```